# how to get rid of Js Undefined from here?

Tags: javascript, trie

[image]my code is okay and output comes into console. but in my span tag result(firstname) shows undefined. i can't understand what is the problem. can anyone help me to solve this problem? how can i get rid of this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search Baby name</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="first_div" id="div_id">
    <div><p> Baby Names</p></div>
    <div><p> HOW UNIQUE IS YOUR CHILD NAMES IS ?</p></div>
    Enter Full Name : <input type="text" id="input_id" class="input_class">
    <input type="button" class="btn_class" id="btn_id" value="search">
    </br>
    <span id="result">  </span>

</div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
    function insertWord(tree, string) {
        var keys = Object.keys(tree),
            result = keys.some(function (k) {
                    var i = 0;
                    if (string.substr(0, k.length) === k) {
                        string.slice(k.length);
                        return true;
                    }
                    while (k[i] == string[i] && i < k.length) {
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (i) {
                        var id = k.slice(0, i);
                        tree[id] = {
                            [k.slice(i)]: tree[k], [string.slice(i)]: 0
                        }
                        ;
                        delete tree[k];
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            );

        if (!result) {
            tree[string] = 0;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        localStorage.clear();
        $('#input_id').keyup(function (e) {
            fsname = $('#input_id').val();
            var data = fsname.trim();
            var msg = $('#result');
            msg.empty();
            var localdata = localStorage.getItem(data);
            if (data) {
                if (localdata == null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "search.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                            input: data
                        },
                        dataType: "",
                        success: function (name) {
                            var getdata = JSON.parse(name);
                            var tree = {};
                            getdata.forEach(insertWord.bind(null, tree));
                            localStorage.setItem(data, JSON.stringify(tree));
                            console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(data)));
                            console.log(getdata);
                            var s = getdata.length;
                            for (var j = 0; j < s; j++) {
                                if (getdata[j].surname) {
                                    var show = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</div>';
                                    msg.append(show);

                                } else {
                                    var show1 = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + '</div>';
                                    msg.append(show1);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    var getdata = JSON.parse(localdata);
                    var s = getdata.length;
                    for (var j = 0; j < s; j++) {
                        if (getdata[j].surname) {
                            var show = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</div>';
                            msg.append(show);

                        } else {
                            var show1 = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + '</div>';
                            msg.append(show1);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```

i want my firstname here. but it shows undefined. how can i solve this problem? In console my output is pretty okay. and data saved in localstorage.

Comment: `want my firstname here` where? `but it shows undefined` what does?

Comment: if (getdata[j].surname) ... 
i want my expected result here. in if else condition. you got me?

Comment: so `getdata[j].surname` is undefined? what does `localdata` look like at the time? *you got me* - yeah, no need to be rude - I mean, so far 90% of this code is code from so

Comment: I am not able to run this code since it have script error and unbalanced html tag

Comment: actually its not. my expected result is undefined . when press a key. result is  come in span tag which is shows undefined.

Comment: please describe the problem in a manner that allows us to identify where the problem is - so far you just said "I want my firstname here" ... and then that you expect `getdata[j].surname` to be undefined while also you want your expected result in that place - seriously, pretend we can't read your mind or run your code

Comment: @ Jaromanda X localdata is a variable where i save the data in local storage.

Comment: @ Jaromanda X var show = '<div id="result"  is in span tag , where i want to print the result. result comes  but it shows undefined . if 3 names come, 3 undefined is appeared instead of names.

Comment: @JaromandaX i just added a image of my problem. can you please see this . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid, appending multiple elements with the same id `var show = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</div>'; msg.append(show);`

Yet `msg` is the element with the id of `result`;

- Note it is also invalid to have a span contain a block element such as a div.
- Why include jQuery multiple times?
- Implied global variables,
- `</br>` is invalid,
- `fsname` is global (undefined)
- missing semi-colons,
- Are you SURE you want keyup? in `$('#input_id').keyup(function(e) {` doing ajax on each keyup without throttle? What if I press the "a" key and hold it down? I get multiple "aaaaa" Perhaps use a 'change' event?
- localStorage.clear(); in the document ready event handler indicates you MAY wish to use sessionStorage instead.
- `localStorage.setItem(data, JSON.stringify(tree));` is puzzling normally it would look like `localStorage.setItem("mytree", JSON.stringify(tree));` or similar then use `localStorage.getItem("mytree");` to access it
- `fsname = $('#input_id').val();` you are already in the event handler for that so use `fsname = $(this).val();`
- `$(document).ready(function () {` better written as `$(function () {` as the recommended method https://api.jquery.com/ready/
- rewrite your `var show = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</div>';` something like `var show = '<span class="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + (!!getdata[j].surname && !!getdata[j].surname)? getdata[j].surname :""  + '</span>';`

i.e. take this group of lines

```
if (getdata[j].surname) {
     var show = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + " " + getdata[j].surname + '</div>';
     msg.append(show);
 } else {
     var show1 = '<div id="result">' + getdata[j].firstname + '</div>';
     msg.append(show1);
 }
```

rewrite as these two lines

```
 var showName = getdata[j].firstname + " " + (!!getdata[j] && !!getdata[j].surname)? getdata[j].surname :"";
 msg.append('<span class="result">'  + showName + '</span>');
```

While you are at it, make your code more DRY.

Put that last in a function and call it instead of putting it in twice conditionally.

Make the span (result) a DIV if you want to use blocks (div) inside it instead.

Comment: yeah i saw what you said. how can i get rid of this problem? can you help me to do that ? Thanks

Comment: You have many other issues in this code.  Why include jQuery multiple times?  Implied global variables, `</br>` is invalid, `fsname` is global (undefined)  missing semi-colons, Are you SURE you want `keyup`? in `$('#input_id').keyup(function(e) {` doing ajax on each keyup without throttle? What if I press the "a" key and hold it down? I get multiple "aaaaa"  Perhaps use a 'change' event?

Comment: Also `localStorage.clear();` in the document ready event handler indicates you MAY wish to use sessionStorage instead.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Schultheiss . but can help me to fix this code?

Comment: I added a list of things to fix

Comment: I just read your things man. i appreciate you for your help. I fix it and let you know what happen after fixing. :) Much More Thanks to you.